# Stop Loading Nodes in Ajax Loading / Lazy Loading in JSTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using JSTree with Ajax Loading / Lazy Loading functionality in my application.

Now I am trying to Open All nodes. So in Loaded event i write open_all method to open all nodes.

```
$('#DIVTree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'multiple': false,
            'data': {
                'url': appRootDir + 'Tree/GetFilterList',
                'data': function (node) {
                    return { 'ID': node.id};
                }
            }
        },
        'plugins': ['state'],
}).on('loaded.jstree', function (node) {
    $('#DIVTree').jstree(true).open_all();
});
```

Now this starts opening all node which i actually wanted.

But now i am having one more button Cancel.

I want to allow user to stop loading nodes when the cancel button is pressed.

I tried lots of ways. I tried to implement recursion with "after_open" event and "load_node" event.

```
$('#DIVTree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'multiple': false,
            'data': {
                'url': appRootDir + 'Tree/GetFilterList',
                'data': function (node) {
                    return { 'ID': node.id };
                }
            }
        },
        'plugins': ['state'],
}).on('load_node.jstree', function (node) {
        if (recrusiveStop == false) {
            OpenNodes();
        }
}).on('after_open.jstree', function (node) {
        if (recrusiveStop == false) {
            OpenNodes();
        }
});

var OpenNodes = function () {
    var nodeID = '';

    $('#DIVTree .jstree-closed').each(function () {
        if ($('#DIVTree').jstree(true).is_loaded(this.id) == false) {
            nodeID = this.id;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (nodeID != '') {
        $('#DIVTree').jstree(true).open_node(nodeID);
    }
}
```

But still unable to implement.

In "after_open" event is fired only once. So only one node is expanded (not having sub-node) so not staying in loop. while i still want to expand siblings.

**Is there any clear way to implement this?**

**I want to Open all nodes and also stop loading when user hits cancel button.**

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to stop loading once `open_all` is invoked. It will keep loading until there are no nodes with the `jstree-closed` class in the tree container.

Maybe you could approach this differently - return all nested children along with the first request. That way everything will be loaded in a single (or a few) requests instead of one request for each node. Provided your tree is not too big that will be pretty fast and there will be nothing to cancel.

Sorry, but there is no other solution from what I can see. No way to stop the `open_all` call.

Comment: Hello vakata, My TreeView is too big. I am showing very large data. Using Recursion i think i can achieve above functionality. But the performance is reduced. Is there any other approach to work with this scenario? Thanks for support.

Comment: You could create a simple minimal plugin that overrides the `open_all` function and adds a new `stop_open_all` function. It can all work with a simple variable that will indicate to `open_all` to stop.

Comment: Above example with 'load_node' and 'after_open' works recursively and allows me to stop opening node. but as i said it reduces the performance. Thanks vakata i will try.